# I'm trying to use yarn link and other folder says me it is not a module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, yarnpkg

Whenever I try to use "yarn link" its says success. When I try to use it in another project It says `../../.tsx is not a module`  What I'm missing ?

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false)
const node = React.useRef(null)

return (
  <>
    <div ref={node} >
      <Burger open={open} setOpen={setOpen} />
      <Menu open={open} setOpen={setOpen} />

      </div>
    </>
)

}

export default App
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yarn link uses relative pathing.

So if you're trying to use it in another project, you need to ensure the relative path still makes sense. Meaning you might need to traverse up more/fewer directories (the `../`)

Also, verify that you're pointing to a valid module, as the error states: `../../.tsx` is not a valid module... it should be something more like `../../module.tsx`